# Como inserir uma variável no meio do endereço que eu passar para UrlLib2?

Tags: python

Estou usando a função `urllib2` em Python e preciso colocar uma variável no meio do link que eu passar pra função.
Por exemplo:

```
request = urllib2.Request('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/id_user?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow')
```

Onde o `id_user` é uma variável. Como faço ele reconhecer o `id_user` como uma variável?

Comment: Resolvido, url = "%s%d%s"%("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/",id_user ,"?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow"). Dessa forma ele reconhece em cada intervalo antes, entre e depois das virgulas onde cada argumento será predefinido. String vírgula inteiro vírgula string. Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar.

Comment: Senhor Sunstreaker, dê uma lida direito na pergunta, você vai perceber que existe um "user_id" no meio da link, e logo após eu deixei explicativo "Onde o id_user é uma variável." Muito obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 3):

Há algumas formas de fazer isso.

Operador [`modulo %`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```
id_User = "IdUserNameAqui"
request = urllib2.Request('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/%s?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow' % id_User)
```

Operador [`unário +`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations):

```
id_User = "IdUserNameAqui"
request = urllib2.Request('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/' + str(id_User) + '?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow')
```

Função [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
id_User = "IdUserNameAqui"
request = urllib2.Request("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/{0}?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow".format(id_User))
```

### Exemplo

O exemplo abaixo vai inserir o conteúdo de uma variável no meio da URL, fazer a requisição e pegar algumas informações do *JSON* retornado.

```
import requests
#Para instalar: sudo pip install requests

id_User = "1"
url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/{0}?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow".format(id_User)
json = requests.get(url).json()

accountID  = json['items'][0]['account_id']
websiteURL = json['items'][0]['website_url']
userName   = json['items'][0]['display_name']

print ("ID: {0}\nNome de exibicao: {1}\nSite: {2}\n".format(accountID, userName, websiteURL))

# Saída
# ID: 1
# Nome de exibicao: Jeff Atwood
# Site: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o método [format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
id_user = 1
url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/{0}?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow'
request = urllib2.Request(url.format(id_user))
```

Você pode usar o %, desta forma:

```
url = "...users/%s?order..." % id_user
```

Irá funcionar, mas prefira sempre o método format(). Como descrito pela [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) oficial, ele trata erros comuns de concatenação, e será o método oficial usado pelo Python daqui para frente. A idéia é que em breve o % não seja mais aceito.

Você também pode usar o "plus operation":

```
url = '...user/' + id_user + '?order...'
```

Mas é uma péssima prática. Quando o código se torna maior (e você deve sempre pensar nisso), esta url será ilegível. Caso precise juntar duas strings de forma rápida, prefira usar o join().

```
url = ''.join(['...user/',
               id_user,
               '?order...'])
```

Resumindo, use o [format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). É o que o Python pede para que você use, no fim das contas.